# How to replace an ImageView by another one in an Array?

Tags: java, android, arrays, xml, imageview

so this is my xml code:

```
<ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_weight="1">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="200dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/profilbildfrau"
                android:id="@+id/bild0"/>

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="200dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/profilbildfrau"
                android:id="@+id/bild1"/>

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="200dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/profilbildfrau"
                android:id="@+id/bild2"/>

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_weight="1">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="200dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/profilbildfrau"
                android:id="@+id/bild3"/>

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="200dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/profilbildfrau"
                android:id="@+id/bild4"/>

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="200dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/profilbildfrau"
                android:id="@+id/bild5"/>

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_weight="1">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="200dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/profilbildfrau"
                android:id="@+id/bild6"/>

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="200dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/profilbildfrau"
                android:id="@+id/bild7"/>

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="200dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/profilbildfrau"
                android:id="@+id/bild8"/>

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_weight="1">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="200dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/profilbildfrau"
                android:id="@+id/bild9"/>

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="200dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/profilbildfrau"
                android:id="@+id/bild10"/>

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="200dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/profilbildfrau"
                android:id="@+id/bild11"/>

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_weight="1">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="200dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/profilbildfrau"
                android:id="@+id/bild12"/>

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="200dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/profilbildfrau"
                android:id="@+id/bild13"/>

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="200dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/profilbildfrau"
                android:id="@+id/bild14"/>

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_weight="1">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="200dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/profilbildfrau"
                android:id="@+id/bild15"/>

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="200dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/profilbildfrau"
                android:id="@+id/bild16"/>

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="200dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/profilbildfrau"
                android:id="@+id/bild17"/>

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_weight="1">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="200dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/profilbildfrau"
                android:id="@+id/bild18"/>

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="200dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/profilbildfrau"
                android:id="@+id/bild19"/>

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="200dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/profilbildfrau"
                android:id="@+id/bild20"/>


        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_weight="1">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="200dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@android:color/black"
                android:id="@+id/bild21"
                android:visibility="gone"/>

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="200dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@android:color/black"
                android:id="@+id/bild22"
                android:visibility="gone"/>

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="200dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@android:color/black"
                android:id="@+id/bild23"
                android:visibility="gone">

            </ImageView>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
```

And these imageViews are inside an array in my java file:

```
    profilbilder[0] = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.bild0);
        profilbilder[1] = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.bild1);
        profilbilder[2] = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.bild2);
        profilbilder[3] = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.bild3);
        profilbilder[4] = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.bild4);
        profilbilder[5] = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.bild5);
        profilbilder[6] = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.bild6);
        profilbilder[7] = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.bild7);
        profilbilder[8] = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.bild8);
        profilbilder[9] = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.bild9);
        profilbilder[10] = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.bild10);
        profilbilder[11] = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.bild11);
        profilbilder[12] = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.bild12);
        profilbilder[13] = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.bild13);
        profilbilder[14] = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.bild14);
        profilbilder[15] = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.bild15);
        profilbilder[16] = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.bild16);
        profilbilder[17] = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.bild17);
        profilbilder[18] = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.bild18);
        profilbilder[19] = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.bild19);
        profilbilder[20] = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.bild20);
        profilbilder[21] = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.bild21);
        profilbilder[22] = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.bild22);
        profilbilder[23] = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.bild23);
```

The three last images are visibility:gone. When I click on one of the other pictures, I want the picture that was clicked on to disappear and one of the three "gone" pictures should take its place.

```
    for(int i = 0; i <= 20; i++){

        profilbilder[i].setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view){
                setVisible(false);
                profilbilder[profilZähler].setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                profilZähler++;
                Intent profilIntent = new Intent(Hauptmenue.this, Profil.class);
                startActivity(profilIntent);
            }
        });
    }
```

That's how I tried to achieve it, but that won't work. Anyone has any suggestions on how I can reach my goal?

Thank you,
Julian

Comment: Why are you not using a RecylerView or a ListView?

Comment: didnt know about RecyclerView, can that help me with my goal?

Answer (score 1):

What is profilZähler .? 
Also use this instead of setVisible(false);
profilbilder[i].setVisibility(View.GONE);

You are launching a new activity on the OnClickListener, when you comeback your view will be the same so you need to refresh the view.
Also, you have not written the functionality to make the last three images visible.

From what I understand from your layout you have 3 images in a horizontal layout and have around 8 such layouts.

If you want to hide the image on click and replace it with the last three image. is it in the view, or in the Array?

if it is in the view simply replace the image in say bild3 with the image in bild21.

if in the array replace the element with logic.
int i=0, int j=5, int temp = 0;
temp = j; j = i;, i = temp;

can you be a little more specific on what your error is and what do want to achieve..?
Thanks.

Another Solution.
After giving it a thought.

How you can do this is create a card(layout) for each image.

let your layout have  8 empty linear layouts.

inflate each of your images into the layout from your code. and add functionality from the code itself.

Ex.

```
<LinearLayout
 id=+/layout1
.....?
```

/>
then you create a card for your image

```
<Layout......>
<ImageView .... ></layout..>
```

the use

```
//chk out the syntax.
View view = LayoutInflator.inflate(card,parent..... )
layout1.add(view);
```

something like here https://github.com/iamShekharGH/RealmAndroidExample/blob/master/MyApplication/app/src/main/java/com/iamshekhargh/realmexample/Fragments/FragmentAddDetails.java

line 157.

Comment: profilZähler is a variable that begins at 21 and counts upwards whenever a picture is clicked. So when I click picture one, it should be replaced by picture 21, then 22 and so on

How do I refresh the view correctly in this example?

Probably having the pictures in another horizontal Layout is a bad idea, so my goal is to have 21 pictures in a scroll view. When i click on any one of them I get pointed to another activity and when I come back from that other activity,

Comment: I want the picture I clicked on to be replaced by another picture. What you saw there was a desperate try, if you know how to do it, i would gladly hear it! Thank you!

Comment: So what you can do is dont make the visibility gone.. replace the image.

Comment: or a better idea would be to write a function to replace that particular element with the new one . and refresh the whole view when you come back.

Comment: how would that function look like? or can you give me a starting point? :D

Comment: pass the ImageView to the function, create a temp ImageView, and then switch, replace it using the two. 
checkout the code above . that would be a better option for you.

Comment: So I dont put any images in the xml and just have empty layouts and then code everything in java? never done that, should give it a try i guess. I have to set up every imageview with picture and size and position, or?

Comment: you can put the image from the code itself. you just have to make a layout with just a imageView inside it.

Comment: so i have to write profilbilder[1].setBackground(...) for every one of the pictures? or is there a faster way? How do I acess just the image that I clicked on though? Does it work with my onClickListener? Thats such a new terrain for me :D

Comment: you can write a function and pass the view and image to it as arguments. put that function in a loop. That will save you writing some of the code. but I guess you'll have to write most of it..

Answer (score 0):

Your ImageView can't clickable. Please add `android:clickable="true"` and try again. Or you can use ImageButton instead of ImageView. Hope it help you!

Comment: it is clickable because of the onClickListener, so the intent and stuff works, just the replacing part doesnt, thanks though!

Comment: I see you used the same background for all ImageView. Are you sure your code not work? I try your code in my sample and it work well. Why you don't check it with Log.d("TAG", "" + profilbilder[profilZähler].getVisibility());

Comment: for the three that should take the place of the clicked on picture i have a black background. I dont get any errors, but the images wont get replaced.